# How can I control the class object which implements multi interface effectively?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, interface-segregation-principle

The goal of the method:ClientProgram::deleteObject() is to delete the target object. And it shows the detail info of the object before deleting it.

```java
//#1. Client program which delete the target object.
public class ClientProgram {
    List<AbstractBase>list = new ArrayList<ConcreteA>();

    void deleteObject(String key) {
        for(AbstractBase obj : list){
            if(!obj.isTarget(key))continue;

            //show info and delete the object
            Msg( obj.getInfo().toString() );
            obj.delete();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It is feasible when the concrete class extends from the abstract base class (like below #2,#3) or an interface with multi methods.

```java
//#2. A base abstract class for concrete classes
public abstract class AbstractBase {
    public abstract boolean isTarget(String key);
    public abstract void delete();
    public abstract void update(AbstractBase obj);
    public abstract AbstractBase getInfo();
}

//#3. A concrete class with an abstract class
public class ConcreteA extends AbstractBase {
     ....
}
```

But once all the methods are segregated into four different interface like #4 (as the ISP is applied), you can only control the concrete object with either one of the segregated interface and cannot call getInfo() and delete() at the same time.

```java
//#4. A concrete class with segregated interfaces
public class ConcreteA implements Delete, Update, GetInfo, Target {
    ....
}
```

What is the best/common practice for creating a method like deleteObject() using the ISPed class like #4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to use ISP 
your version #4 looks good , but you cannot use it to deleteObject ,

so here is solution

```
class MyInfo {
    //some fields
}

interface Delete {
    void delete();
}

interface Info {
    MyInfo getInfo();
}

interface Update {
}

interface Target {
    boolean isTarget();
}

interface ClientProgramm extends Delete, Info, Target {

}

class ConcreteA implements ClientProgramm {

    @Override
    public void delete() {

    }

    @Override
    public MyInfo getInfo() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTarget() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

all your interfaces and classes are independent , and you can collect some necessary logic into interface `ClientProgramm` ,
 for more flexibility you can split `ClientProgramm` to 2 different interfaces like `UpdateObject` and `DeleteObject`

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia page about interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

> In the field of software engineering, the interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.)

In your case, your client does depend on both `getInfo()` and `delete()`; therefore, you should segregate your interface at the granularity that both are included.

Another way to think of ISP is that you build an interface for each client. Sometimes, the same interface is usable by multiple clients, but typically an interface establishes the contract between itself and one client.